# openshift ghost mail config

Tags: openshift, ghost-blog

I installed ghost via Openshift. When signing in I get a sendmail/email configuration popup.  Ghost appears to be attempting to use sendmail.  I updated the config.js file (via git push) to use gmail.  I still get the popup.  Either config isn't being read/used or my push isn't successful (it appears to be).  Any ideas?

Fritz

Comment: Does that same configuration work correctly while running on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Hy Fritz,

You should try reloading the openshift application so it's reading the config.js file again:

```
rhc app reload
```

Or if that doesnt seem to be enouguh you can restart it with

```
rhc app restart
```